# Display object in javascript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I write a script to make an ajax call here is my code

```
function ajax_post(obj) {
    obj = '#'+ obj; 

    var formData = $(obj).serializeArray();    

    $.ajax({
        url: '__core/info.php',
        type:'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,
        success: function(resp){
            alert(resp);
        }
    })
}
```

and here is my info.php

```
$last_Res = theme::get_last_themes_desk(); //$last_Res is an array 
echo(json_encode($last_Res));
```

but when alert it shows return object object ..... what should i do if datatype is json should i convert it to another format ?  $last_Res is an array

Comment: alert's can not show objects, try using the console (F12) -> `console.log(resp)`

Comment: how can i alert my $last_res[0] can i?

Comment: in console.log its ok but i want to alert a part 1 of my array but how ?

Comment: @adeneo is right, the alert will display `[Object object]` when the variable you pass is (you guessed it) an object. You are getting an object because jQuery is parsing the JSON into an object for you. Just use the object.

Comment: @user1718141: Yes, of course you can. Try `alert(resp[0])` (as long as it really is an array). But as adeneo already said, alert isn't a good way to examine the object.

Comment: can you show us the true content of $last_Res ?

Comment: You don't have an array, you have a json encoded object, and to show it you need to know it's properties, which you can see in the console, and use dot or bracket notation to get the property value.

Comment: [{"id":"2","name":"babak_theme","sh_describ":"support css3 and ie 9 ","rate":"3","time":"2"}]

Comment: `resp[0].id //displays "2"` unless resp[0] displays the entire string, then you'd have to parse it as JSON first with `$.parseJSON(resp[0])`

Comment: @adeneo tanx my friend u helped me so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to your comment (showing the response data, which is an array, containing a single object):

```
//resp = [{"id":"2","name":"babak_theme","sh_describ":"support css3 and ie 9 ","rate":"3","time":"2"}];
resp = resp[0];
alert('id => ' + resp.id + ', Name => ' + resp.name);//etc...
```

Will serve you just fine...

`$last_Res` is an *associative array*, most likely. JS doesn't have assoc arrays, but converts these to objects/ object literals:

```
//php:
$foo = array('foo' => 'bar');
//in JS:
var foo = {foo: 'bar'};
alert(foo);//alerts [object Object]
console.log(foo);//shows you what properties/prototypes/methods the object has
```

That's all there is too it. To access the data:

```
for (var prop in resp)
{//for "assoc arrays"
    if (resp.hasOwnProperty(prop))
    {
        alert(prop + ' => '+resp[prop]);
    }
}
for (var i=0;i<resp.length;i++)
{//for regular arrays
    alert(i + ' => ' + resp[i])'
}
```

Comment: or just use `jQuery.each()`.

Comment: my firedn it returns 0=>[object object] again

Comment: @user1718141, of course: it's still an object. That's why I proceeded to add an example that alerts `resp.id` <-- the `.id` part accesses a single property of an object. I'm sorry, but if that still throws you, [MDN has a good crash course on Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: @jpo: Why use a jQ method on a native JS type, that's just not necessary. Sure premature optimization is the root of all evil, but at least consider the pro's and con's of what you do on a basic level

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem: Because he has already included the jQuery library and it iterates over both (literal objects and arrays) just fine. The performance loss is minimal.

Comment: that shows it realize this  [{"id":"2","name":"babak_theme","sh_describ":"support css3 and ie 9 ","rate":"3","time":"2"}]   like a object that means all of this shows resp[0] yeah ? and if i have 2 arrays

like this 
[{"id":"2","name":"babak_theme","sh_describ":"support css3 and ie 9 ","rate":"3","time":"2"}]

Comment: and 
[{"id":"3","name":"ssss_theme","sh_describ":"support css3 and ie 9 ","rate":"3","time":"2"}]  it realize all of this resp[1] ?

Comment: @user1718141, I'm not sure I get what you're saying. But ` [{"id":"3","name":"ssss_theme","sh_describ":"support css3 and ie 9 ","rate":"3","time":"2"}]` is an array of, that contains 1 object. Access it using index 0. If your array looks like this: `[{"id":"3","name":"ssss_theme","sh_describ":"support css3 and ie 9 ","rate":"3","time":"2"},{"id":"2","name":"foo_theme","sh_describ":"support css3 and ie 9 ","rate":"3","time":"2"}]`, then it's an array with 2 objects. Basically: the brackets (`[]`) are the beginning and end of the array, and curlies (`{}`) delimit an object

Comment: Just look for this pattern: `[{},{},{}]` -> 1 array, containing 3 objects. `[{x:[]}]` <- 1 array, containing 1 object that has a property that is an array etc... Bottom line: the first and last _character_ in the response string matter: if it's a bracket (`[`), you're dealing with an array. If it's a curly brace (`{`), you're dealing with an object

Answer (score 1):

In your info.php, you should set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` to indicate what you are returning:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't posted the json format. usually you can access resp. values like this:

if the json format is:

```
data['index']['subindex1'] = 'value1'
data['index']['subindex2'] = 'value2'
```

you can

```
alert(resp.index.subindex1);
```